# Running a developed Program with java 1.2 (SSFnet) with java 8

Tags: java, segmentation-fault

I am trying to build [SSFnet](http://www.ssfnet.org/homePage.html) simulator which is a network simulator developed in Java JDK 1.2.

After downloading it, I am trying to build it, but I got errors such as some unsafe functions has been used or some unsafe input has been used in your program etc. The problem is that I am using java 8 to run a program which has been developed with Java 1.2. Specifically, I get this error:

```
error: as of release 5, 'enum' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
```

and

```
(use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
5 errors
Makefile:114: recipe for target 'SSF.OS' failed
make: *** [SSF.OS] Error 1
```

I tried to install java JDK 1.2 on my machine, but I get `fragmentation fault kernel dumped` error
I do not know if this is possible to run a program which has been developed with Java 1.2 with Java 8 or not and how can I handle this unsafe errors. I have no idea what should I do!

Comment: This looks like too separate questions: 1) How to get SSFnet running on Java 8?   2) How to get JDK 1.2 running on Ubuntu?  This might be the right place to ask question #1, but question #2 would be better on https://askubuntu.com/.  For question #1 you'll need to provide a lot more information, like specific error messages and what you've tried to do to work around those errors.

Comment: Hi @StephenM Thank you for your comment, you are right, let me run SSFnet with Java8, I will edit my question and add the error messages.

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to fix the code.  If you aren't comfortable with that you might pursue the JDK 1.2 option.  The error you listed above should run/compile under Java 1.4, since Java 1.5 (aka 5) is when enum became a keyword.  So, you might have better luck installing JDK 1.4 on your Ubuntu system and running it there.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to install JDK 1.4 from a bin file, executing the bin file gives me a .rpm file and when I try to execute the rpm file, i get this error "/install.sfx.13530: 1: ./install.sfx.13530: ��: not found". It seems I will have a pain for this

Comment: Trying to resurrect old software is often painful.  You are experiencing "code rot" unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure how you "executed" the RPM file, but you need RPM to install an RPM file.  RPM doesn't usually come with Ubuntu, but it can be installed.  Maybe this helps?

Comment: you are right, I installed rpm package for running my .rpm file. I should be more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but javac -source 1.2 should do the trick.
According to the docs you should be able to use "source 1.2" in the javac 1.6 compiler.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: thanks, I am using "make" command in the root folder of my software to build the SSFnet. I can not understand how can I use this option in my case? I mean I use something like this "javac source 1.2 make"  but it does not work :(

Comment: I see. That's a whole different kind of pudding. I suggest looking at your makefile, look at the docs (man make), or a tutorial somewhere (eg. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/)

Comment: You would probably have to edit the Makefile.  Somewhere it is calling javac.  Also, -source 1.2 might be deprecated in newer versions of Java.  Not sure when it was deprecated.